# Encryption using blinded key

Tags: encryption, symmetric, blinding

I was wondering whether there are any "blinded" encryption schemas, such as the following:

We encrypt message $m$ using $f(k)$, where $f()$ is some blinding function and $c = \text{Enc}(f(k), m)$, while the decryption works as $m' = \text{Dec}(k, c)$ and $m' = m$.

One possible option is, of course, public-key encryption schemas, but I was thinking about more efficient (in terms of performance) symmetric key encryption schemas which have this property.

Comment: You are blinding the key, not the message. Blind the message and use CTR mode.

Comment: @kelalaka Can you give me some details how blinding the message will obfuscate k?

Comment: If you look at RSA blinding that uses the mathematical property of RSA. A block cipher has many operations with many rounds, the only meaningful blinding, afaik, is x-or, however that brings no benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be a requirement that, given $f(k)$ and $c$, it is hard to rederive $m$?

If so, then what you are effectively asking for is a public key encryption system; your public key is $f(k)$, and your private key is $k$.
Such a method can be constructed from any public key encryption algorithm (but isn't any more efficient than the underlying pk algorithm).

If not, then it is easy; here is one construction:

- Let $f(k)$ be a randomized function $f(k) = r || \text{hash}( r, k )$.
- To encrypt, you compute $\text{Enc}(f(k), m) = r || \text{AES}( \text{hash}(r, k), m )$.
- To decrypt, you compute $\text{Dec}(k, (r || c)) = \text{AES}^{-1}( \text{hash}(r, k), c )$

Comment: Thanks! Given that it is required that it is hard to retrieve m you just confirm my suspicion that only the public key encryption schema will help. But the second part of your answer is also an inetersting one!